# Android like resource handling for XCode

Tags: xcode, resources, android-resources

Android has a very elegant way of handling resources by generating the R file. In XCode this option is not available and strings are used to address images and other resources. This is problematic as there is no compile time check for the availability of a resource.

As I really needed it, I put together a little script for retina images and added a build phase for it.

```
#!/bin/bash

# Create a header file for the retina images
workingdir=`dirname $0`
output_file="$workingdir/Resources.h"

cat > $output_file << EOH

//
//  Resources.h
//  `date`
EOH

for i in `find $workingdir -name "*@2x.*"`; do
    file=`basename $i`;
    resource_name=${file%%@*};
    def_name=${resource_name//-/_}
cat >> $output_file << EOD
// $i
#define R_${def_name} @"$resource_name"

EOD
done
```

Is there a well established tool for doing this? Or everyone is relying solely on strings?